# println (and all of kotlin.io) show up as 'unresolved reference' in IntelliJ after updating kotlin to version 1.4.10 from 1.3.72

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

In, quite literally a hello world project the IDE seems to think `println` and any other parts of `kotlin.io` are not resolved.

[image: Unresolved reference]

The project builds and runs just fine, however. The issue exists in 1.4.0 but not 1.3.72.

The io package in `kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar` the IDE seems to think is missing, even though it really isn't (ss attached) [image: missing io package]

The following is my `build.gradle`. Changing `1.4.10` to `1.3.72` fixes all the problems.

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
}

group = "ga.rubydesic"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of IDE, Kotlin IDE plugin, and Gradle do you use? You can create an issue here - https://kotl.in/issue

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar-sounding issue and wanted to add what happened / solved it:

Our code was using 1.4.20, but a gradle dependency was causing us to also include 1.4.30. Gradle didn't care, but it caused IntelliJ to stop resolving kotlin.io. Weirdly, existing IntelliJ projects continued to work, but fresh checkouts were seeing the problem.

Once we upgraded to 1.4.30, IntelliJ was fine again. Seemingly, multiple 1.4.x versions caused this problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just ran into this while trying out jetpack compose for desktop and updating kotlin plugin to 1.4.30 took care of it 

Answer (score 0):

I have noted the same issue in IntelliJ 2020.2, Kotlin 1.4.10 and gradle.  Switching back to 1.3.72 works fine. Funny thing is it compiles ok, just red markers for things like println and listOf and no code completion.